# Did Iranian media pixelate most of a female beach volleyball player?

Tags: photography, iran

From https://twitter.com/dr_rafizadeh/status/762752071233708032 a picture of a women's beach volleyball match is shown with an unpixelated Egyptian player, and an almost entirely pixelated other player:

[image]

The tweet says that is censorship in Iran. Is the photo from media in Iran?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/neginsh/status/762760810078887937) notes that it is a joke, and not for real, and links to the original tweet, https://twitter.com/tansimnews/status/762684679161978880 . The Twitter account @Tansimnews has in its profile a link to the website of satirical news service The Onion.

[This Iranian news article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160912064158/http://khabarone.ir/news/3105064) blurred out a German player (see the final image in the set and compare with [this version](https://cdn.newsday.com/polopoly_fs/1.12145261.1470616024!/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/display_960/image.jpg)).

Comment: @called2voyage: Perhaps he reads Arabic? Lots of people do, you know.

Comment: @TonyK Probably Farsi, not Arabic, but regardless he should clarify how he knows--a quotation might help.

Comment: Also, is khabarone.ir a well known news outlet? Saying that it is "accurate" that Iranian media behaves this way would require this to be representative of most Iranian media. What if this is a fringe news outlet?

Comment: @called2voyage this is why I don't think broad conclusions are always useful in an answer. It would be better to just describe the facts and let readers decide if it is "accurate"

Comment: @Dawn I agree. In this case, I daresay it is irrelevant. The answer to the picture addressed in the question is that it is fake. The rest just makes it seem like the OP created the question to characterize the Iranian media a certain way, true or not.

Comment: Can you point to the picture in which the blurring of the German occurred? I don't see it.

Comment: @DJClayworth it's the last one, to the left of the left iranian woman. http://www.mashreghnews.ir/files/fa/news/1395/5/18/1787425_785.jpg